# Load Google Map Directly to specified Address in iPhone

Tags: iphone

How to load Google Map - Specific area map - specified address by user in UItextField?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I Got the solution by r&d.

See the code following.

```
-(IBAction)showAddress // after adding the Address into textField - button pressed{
[addressField resignFirstResponder];
MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta=0.05;
span.longitudeDelta=0.05;
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self addressLocation];
region.span=span;
region.center=location;
if(addAnnotation != nil) 
{
    [mapView removeAnnotation:addAnnotation];
    [addAnnotation release];
    addAnnotation=nil;
}
addAnnotation = [ [AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];
[mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
[mapView regionThatFits:region];
[mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
```

}

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) addressLocation {
//   NSString *urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",[addressField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",[addressField.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
double latitude=0.0;
double longitude=0.0;
if([listItems count] >=4  && [ [listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"])
{
    latitude = [ [listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
    longitude = [ [listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error"); 
}
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude=latitude;
location.longitude=longitude;
return location;
```

}